# Do peers rotate?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, peers, node-discovery, discovery-protocol

Once you have 25 peers, do you keep those same 25 peers (assuming the machines stay up)?

I'm having a problem (discussed other places) that would be more easily explained if part of the peer discovery algorithm was to bump old peers and get new ones every so often.

Does that happen?